# Terminal program with multiplexing, for Windows

Tags: windows, terminal-multiplexer

I'm looking for a terminal program for Windows - like PuTTY - with the following features:

- **Multiplexing** i.e. the user can open multiple terminal sessions at the same time and send the same command to all sessions at once
- Free to use
- **Portable** i.e. it does not need admin privileges to be installed on the local machine

So far I've found [ConEmu](https://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html) but it's not a stable version, it's still in alpha.