# multi-terminal application for windows

Tags: windows, gratis, terminal-emulator, terminal-multiplexer

I have a machine which has Win10 installed, along with Cygwin, whose terminal I use (`mintty`). Also, I use that machine for long SSH sessions to other machines, in parallel with work on the machine itself.

I would like to be able to hold all of these shell sessions in a single application, as tabs (or in some other relevant arrangement), and in a way which would make it relatively easy for me tell them apart. It is thus important to me to be able to set some or all of the following:

- Tab header background color
- Tab header foreground color
- Tab title (or title prefix etc.)
- Tab header font weight / color
- Terminal colors
- Terminal font and font size

... for individual tabs (or categories of tabs).

It's essential that this happen for local shell sessions (with Cygwin's bash) - not just remote connections. In fact, *just* local sessions is already ok - like terminal multiplexers on Unix machines, since you can ssh from that terminal. Support for Windows Powershell and/or regular command shell is also important, though less critical.

This question is related to, but not the same as, [this one](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/67305/terminal-program-with-multiplexing-for-windows).

Answer (score 1):

[ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) might fit the bill. It claims to support both WinAPI console programs as well as Unix-style pty programs - which should include the Cygwin shell.

Screenshot:

[image]

It has some capability of differentiating the console windows from each other:

- Tab titles can be set arbitrarily.
- A tab can get a background logo set.
- Terminal colors can be set to one of multiple palettes; and the palettes can e edited by you.

there are possibly other "customization points" - may not have found them all yet.